# Python using thread event as an object member

Tags: python, multithreading, events

I have a class, for example like the following

```
Class Example(object):
   trigger_event = threading.Event()

    def set_trigger(self):
        # do some stuff
        self.trigger_event.set()
```

What I am finding is if I have a group of these objects and process them in a single thread, then once the first object has its event set, then all other objects have it set as well. Is there no way to have a unique Event member for each individual object?

If I have 10 objects, and print out the is_set() for the Event before I call set_trigger() then it will show as FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE etc...

Thanks in advance for any help or insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably misinterpreting the `Event` object. The `Event` object is used for communication between multiple threads: one thread signals an event and other threads wait for it.

> An event object manages an internal flag that can be set to true with
>   the set() method and reset to false with the clear() method. The
>   wait() method blocks until the flag is true.

But if you still want to do that, you have to create new event object every time you create new instance of `Example`. So you might have to do something like,

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.trigger_event = threading.Event()

    def set_trigger(self):
        # do some stuff
        self.trigger_event.set()

e1 = Example()
print(e1.trigger_event.is_set())
e1.set_trigger()
print(e1.trigger_event.is_set())

e2 = Example()
print(e2.trigger_event.is_set())
e2.set_trigger()
e2.trigger_event.wait()
print(e2.trigger_event.is_set())
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
False
True
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right - your approach works for my instance. In my actual example I have two threads - a parser and a DB thread, and I needed a way for the parser to know when the DB processed its request so using the event and your suggestion made it work! Thanks again!